# A record duplicates CNAME record

Tags: domain-name-system

My hosting company has set up the DNS records for my site so that there are two entries for `www`:

```
example.com       A       192.0.2.222
www.example.com   A       192.0.2.222
www.example.com   CNAME   example.com
```

Is there a reason for having both an `A` record and a `CNAME` record for `www`?

I now wish to redirect `www` to a completely different site.

I'm guessing that I have to delete the `A` record for `www` and change the `CNAME` record for `www` to refer to the URL of the other site. Is that correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is not. This is actually considered as an error, explained below.

In this case, where you want to *redirect www to a completely different site*, you'd remove both the `CNAME` and the `A` and replace it with another record of either the type `A` or `CNAME`, but not both.

Also notice that `CNAME` works merely as an alias for the canonical name. It won't perform any actual *redirection*, as redirection is a function of the HTTP protocol, instead of DNS.

---

If a hostname has a `CNAME` record, it must not have other resource records of other type. References:

> **[RFC 1912, 2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1912#section-2.4) CNAME records**
>
> A `CNAME` record is not allowed to coexist with any other data.  In
> other words, if `suzy.podunk.xx` is an alias for `sue.podunk.xx`, you can't also have an `MX` record for `suzy.podunk.edu`, or an `A` record, or even a `TXT` record.  Especially do not try to combine `CNAME`s and `NS` records

If you use a `CNAME`, the DNS server should return both `CNAME` record and the `A` record for the *canonical* hostname it's pointing to. The same applies to IPv6 `AAAA` records.

> **[RFC 1034, 3.6.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-3.6.2) Aliases and canonical names**
>
> For example, suppose a name server was processing a query with for
> `USC-ISIC.ARPA`, asking for type `A` information, and had the following
> resource records:
>
> ```
> USC-ISIC.ARPA   IN      CNAME   C.ISI.EDU
>
> C.ISI.EDU       IN      A       10.0.0.52
> ```
>
> Both of these RRs would be returned in the response to the type `A`
> query, while a type `CNAME` or * query should return just the `CNAME`.

The only exception is DNSSEC.

[RFC 2181, 10.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181#section-10.1) allowed `SIG`, `NXT`, and `KEY` records, while the currently used definition is:

> **[RFC 4035, 2.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4035#section-2.5) Changes to the CNAME Resource Record**
>
> If a `CNAME` RRset is present at a name in a signed zone, appropriate
> `RRSIG` and `NSEC` RRsets are REQUIRED at that name.  A `KEY` RRset at that
> name for secure dynamic update purposes is also allowed ([RFC3007]).
> Other types MUST NOT be present at that name.
>
> This is a modification to the original `CNAME` definition given in
> [RFC1034].  The original definition of the `CNAME` RR did not allow any
> other types to coexist with a `CNAME` record, but a signed zone requires
> `NSEC` and `RRSIG` RRs for every authoritative name.  To resolve this
> conflict, this specification modifies the definition of the `CNAME`
> resource record to allow it to coexist with `NSEC` and `RRSIG` RRs.

Comment: Nitpick: RFC 2181 isn't the DNSSEC used nowadays - that's RFC 4034 and friends, with records like NSEC*, RRSIG, DNSKEY and DS.

Comment: Thanks, Esa. I was using the term redirect to describe (maybe incorrectly) the objective I wanted to achieve, rather than as a technical term for the methodology.  I do use HTTP redirection from a PHP script to initially allocate users to servers for their geographical areas (broadly by continent, but one or two individual countries), and then DNS to provide meaningful subdomain names for the actual servers. **www** gets hit by the bots (about 60% of all traffic), so I want to be able to move it to the least-loaded server.

Comment: Thanks, @VladimírČunát, I've fixed this now. Also rearranged this a bit so that it clearly answers to the situation first and then explains the references in detail.

Answer (score 2):

It is a mistake to have both records. You can safely remove A record and edit CNAME to point to another site.